# How to detect the passing of a string literal to a function in C?

Tags: c, string, literals

I am trying to implement an eqivilent version of perl's `chomp()` function in C and I have come across a corner case where a string literal passed as the argument will  cause a segmentation fault (rightfully so).

Example `chomp("some literal string\n");`

Is there a defined way in C99 to detect wether or not my function was passed a string literal so that I can `return` without attempting to NUL it out?

```
char* chomp(char *s)
{
    char *temp = s;

    if (s && *s)
    {
        s += strlen(s) - 1;
        if (*s == '\n')
        {
            *s = '\0';
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Odd. Shouldn't your compiler be preventing a string literal being passed in as an argument that isn't declared as `const char *`?

Comment: @Adam Maras: That is not required by the standard. However, trying to modify the same is UB.

Comment: Adam Maras: In plain C, string literals have type `char *`, not `const char *`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a defined way in C99 to detect wether or not my function was passed a string literal so that I can return without attempting to NUL it out?

You shouldn't.

Your API shouldn't attempt to fudge things for the caller, only to have it break later on. **If the caller breaks the rules, they should find out then and there.**

If the caller passes a non-mutable string to a function that expects a mutable one, it *should* segfault. Anything else is bad design.

(Addendum: The best design, of course, would be to return a copy of the string that the caller is responsible for freeing.)

Comment: Is there a recommended practice other than documentation to alert the caller that this could be a potential memory leak if not `free()`'d?

Comment: @SiegeX - one thing I like to do is include alloc in the names of functions that do that `char *chomp_alloc(const char *);`

Comment: @SiegeX: I would go with `error_t chomp(const char* input, char** out_result)` myself. It's obvious there is something coming out of it that isn't there for syntax, so obviously you have to free it, and you also get a specific error.

Comment: An API that willingly crashes is not just bad design, it's terrible. The really bad design is the C spec allowing string literals to degrade to `char *` with no way to detect it. The caller may not even know that they've passed an immutable string, it may have been given to them.

Answer (score 3):

Your `chomp` should ideally create a new string and return it. There is no way to determine if you were passed a string literal or not. In fact, I'd suggest using the following signature for `chomp`:

```
char *chomp(const char *s); /* do not modify input parameters */
```

Or, you could create two different functions and document them for the clients: use `chomp` for non-literals and `chompl` for literal strings.

Comment: Is there a recommended practice other than documentation to alert the caller that this could be a potential memory leak if not `free()`'d?

Comment: Not exactly. How will you ever know when the client is through using this object? See `strdup` documentation for example.

Answer (score 1):

There is one VERY risky/bad way => Usually string-literals are stored in read-only data section. So one way is to try to write to destination string - if `segmentation fault` is received into `signal callback` - then that means that your string is literal, and return back to test function with `longjmp`.
Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

static jmp_buf jbuf;

static void catch_segv() {
    longjmp(jbuf, 1);
}

int isLiteral(char * ptr) {
  if (setjmp(jbuf) == 0)
    return  (*ptr = *ptr, 0);
  else
    return 1;
  }

int main()
{
    char writableString[] = "some writable string";

    signal(SIGSEGV, catch_segv);

    printf("is literal = %d\n", isLiteral(writableString));
    printf("is literal = %d\n", isLiteral("read-only string"));

    return 0;
}
```

But given that resuming program after `SIGSEGV` is very risky thing and given that string literals are not always stored on read-only data section - this solution is highly un-recommended for production.