# In C, will a literal string address always be greater than any allocated string address?

Tags: c, string, memory-management

I'm attempting to differentiate literal strings from allocated strings so I don't accidentally try to free() literal strings, which would cause a segfault.

The reason I might try to free() literal strings involve a strcat() wrapper that can be embedded thusly:  `strcatex("My name ", strcatex("is ", strMyName));`

Regardless of the reason, consider:

```
void* mallocex(int intBytes) 
{
    void* newPtr;

    newPtr = malloc(intBytes);

    if(newPtr == 0)
        return 0;
    else if(newPtr > maxPointer)
        maxPointer = newPtr;

    return newPtr;
}
```

and

```
int SafeFree(void **ptr)
{
    if((unsigned long) ptr > (unsigned long) maxPointer) 
        return 0;
    else
        free(*ptr);

    return 1;
}
```

example use:

```
char *newString;
newString = (char*) mallocex(12);

strcpy(newString, "Example one");

SafeFree(&newString);
SafeFree("Example two");
```

Will this always work, regardless of how large my heap becomes?

Comment: +1 for casting to `unsigned long` before the comparison, improving the overall portability of your `SafeFree()` function (although it does not work). The type `uint_ptr` would be marginally better, even.

Comment: you can also check [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322647/how-to-detect-the-passing-of-a-string-literal-to-a-function-in-c)

Comment: Thanks, 0x69, I see your answer on that thread, that a setjmp, longjmp is the only feasible (although not recommended) method.  I've decided to rewrite my `char *strcatex(char *stringOne, char *stringTwo);` function to be `char *strcatex(char *stringOne, int doFreeOne, char *stringTwo, int doFreeTwo);` with a simple `if(doFreeOne) free(stringOne);` step.  Thanks for showing how a setjmp, longjmp would work, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such guarantee don't rely on it.
A string literal is allocated memory somewhere in the read-only implementation defined region there is no way to know what that will be in a portable manner and hence you should not make any assumptions about it.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  That's unfortunate, though.  Would some type of setjmp() and longjmp() exception handling approach work for avoiding the segfault?

Comment: @SamPorch: The responsibility of calling `free()` with a valid pointer rests on the caller So I find your approach overkill of defensive programming.

Comment: I see.  Perhaps I should rethink my strcatex() function, then.

Answer (score 1):

The situation is even "worse" than you imagine. Comparison is only defined for pointers that point into the same object (or just to the byte beyond). So generally for two different objects (be they statically allocated as a string literal or dynamically with `malloc` or so) you can't even ask whether or not one has an address that is smaller than the other. On most platforms such a comparison will work, but you can't rely on it in a strict sense.

Comment: The OP casts the pointers to an integer type, which is implementation-defined, and then compares integers. I agree with your remark, but I think that for someone who wants to compare pointers, the OP is at least doing it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Not only are there no guarantees, systems where the opposite is true are pretty common.  On MacOS (my laptop), for instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void pr_addr(const char *name, void *addr) {
    printf("%s: %p\n", name, addr);
}

int main(void) {
    pr_addr("literal", "literal");
    pr_addr("heap", malloc(10));
    return 0;
}
$ cc -o foo -W -Wall -O foo.c
$ ./foo
literal: 0x1ff1
heap: 0x100160
```

So here the `rodata` section is well *below* the start of the `malloc` arena, the opposite of what you see on your system.

In general, systems with fancy segmentation or other structured pointer types are where you wind up with meaningless comparisons between non-adjacent objects.  The test for `p < q` often compiles to comparisons of just the offset-within-segment.  For instance, if both `p` and `q` point to the start of their (different) segments, both of their offsets are zero, even though the addresses are different.  Hence `p < q` and `p > q` are both false and yet `p != q`.

Answer (score 0):

For fun, I wrote an attempt that tries to guess based on addresses of other literals. It works by comparing the address of the potential literal with another known literal, a stack address, and a heap address. If the potential address is closer to the literal than the others, it assumes that the potential address is a literal. It's probably unreliable in practice. Here's a simplistic version of it:

```
int is_literal_simplistic(char *s) {
    char *literal = "literal";
    char stack[] = "stack";
    char *heap = malloc(1);
    free(heap);
    unsigned long literal_delta = labs(literal - s);
    unsigned long stack_delta = labs(stack - s);
    unsigned long heap_delta = labs(heap - s);
    return (literal_delta < stack_delta && literal_delta < heap_delta);
}
```

and here's the more concise version. It can probably be simpler:

```
int is_literal(char *s) {
  char *heap = malloc(1);
  free(heap);
  unsigned long literal_delta = labs("literal" - s);
  unsigned long stack_delta = labs((char *)&s - s);
  unsigned long heap_delta = labs(heap - s);
  return (literal_delta < stack_delta && literal_delta < heap_delta);
}
```

Full runnable test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//#define DEBUG

#ifdef DEBUG
void debug_literal(unsigned long literal,
                   unsigned long stack,
                   unsigned long heap,
                   unsigned long literal_delta,
                   unsigned long stack_delta,
                   unsigned long heap_delta) {
  printf("literal(%lx)  stack(%lx)  heap(%lx)\n", literal, stack, heap);
  printf("literal(%lu)  stack(%lu)  heap(%lu)\n", literal_delta, stack_delta, heap_delta);
  int answer = (literal_delta < stack_delta && literal_delta < heap_delta);
  printf("\t%s\n", answer ? "literal" : "other");
}
#else
void debug_literal(unsigned long literal,
                   unsigned long stack,
                   unsigned long heap,
                   unsigned long literal_delta,
                   unsigned long stack_delta,
                   unsigned long heap_delta) {
}
#endif

int is_literal_simplistic(char *s) {
    char *literal = "literal";
    char stack[] = "stack";
    char *heap = malloc(1);
    free(heap);
    unsigned long literal_delta = labs(literal - s);
    unsigned long stack_delta = labs(stack - s);
    unsigned long heap_delta = labs(heap - s);
    debug_literal((unsigned long)literal, (unsigned long)stack, (unsigned long)heap,
                  literal_delta, stack_delta, heap_delta);
    return (literal_delta < stack_delta && literal_delta < heap_delta);
}

int is_literal(char *s) {
  char *heap = malloc(1);
  free(heap);
  unsigned long literal_delta = labs("literal" - s);
  unsigned long stack_delta = labs((char *)&s - s);
  unsigned long heap_delta = labs(heap - s);
  debug_literal(0,0,0, literal_delta, stack_delta, heap_delta);
  return (literal_delta < stack_delta && literal_delta < heap_delta);
}

void test_literal_function(int(*liternal_fn)(char *)) {
  char *literal = "literal_test";
  char stack[] = "stack_test";
  char *heap = malloc(40);

  printf("\t%s\n", liternal_fn(literal) ? "literal" : "other");
  printf("\t%s\n", liternal_fn(stack) ? "literal" : "other");
  printf("\t%s\n", liternal_fn(heap) ? "literal" : "other");
  printf("\n");

  free(heap);
}

int main() {
  test_literal_function(is_literal_simplistic);
  test_literal_function(is_literal);

  return 0;
}
```